# Can I recover a non-saved activity from my Garmin Forerunner 110?

Tags: garmin

I went on a 40 mile cycle today and just went to upload the activity to Strava and realized I must've pressed the wrong button and I didn't save it.

Is there a way that I can recover the file?

I can see multiple .fit files from today (Running.fit, Settings.fit, Device.fit), all with last modified dates of today, but they're only 1kb and so clearly not big enough to store my ride. My activities folder also has a last modified date of today (but no activity in it).

Is there ANY way possible I can recover the ride?

Comment: If you can download the gpx or original file from Strava you have your file but you'll have to be a subscriber to do it.

Comment: https://the5krunner.com/2016/09/28/garmin-edge-820-recovering-a-discarded-file-probably-applies-to-fenix-920xt-forerunner/ found this on the internet, might work for a Forerunner 110 as well.